# Sqlite Remove Not Null Constraints InMemory

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlite, asp.net-core

How do I remove all Not Null Constraints in SQL Lite Inmemory Database for All Tables?
I have Foreign Keys = false, to remove Foreign Keys.

```
var InMemoryConnectionString = "DataSource=:memory:;Foreign Keys=False";
var _connection = new SqliteConnection(InMemoryConnectionString);

_connection.Open();
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestContext>()
        .UseSqlite(_connection)
        .Options;
var testContext = new TestContext(options);
testContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

Looking to Remove All Constraints would be a better answer.

Getting Not null errors, if All required fields are not filled out.

```
 var seedData= new List<Product>
{
    new Product
    { ProductId = 1, Description = "test" },
    new Product
    { ProductId = 2, Description = "test2" }
};

testContext.Product.AddRange(seedData);
testContext.SaveChanges();
```

> Error:
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException : An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
> ---- Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException : SQLite Error 19: 'NOT NULL constraint failed: Product.ProductNumber'.

Comment: Is this for testing or the application does not require not null constraints?

Comment: Is this _Code First_ or _Database First_? I haven't worked with in-memory DBs before, but I am asking because if it is _Code First_, I believe you will need to remove the FKs in the Class files. I don't believe you can add _Foreign Keys=False_ to the Connection String and remove the FKs.

Comment: Show us the model for Product.

Comment: hi @rick question is for All tables

Comment: There aren't any 'settings' to sweepingly remove all constraints..

Comment: You could always create a new table without  constraints, copy the data, then delete the old table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's SQLite that's enforcing the constraint, it's doing this because of your Entity Framework (EF) model(s).  When the context is setup, if a model-property is decorated as `[Required]` then EF adds a not-null constraint the the database.  If you wish to allow this to be null, you should remove the `[Required]` attribute.

#### Example failing model

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Will throw an `SQLite Error 19` (as you're seeing):

```cs
ctx.Products.Add(new Product() { ProductId = 3});
ctx.SaveChanges(); //SQLite Error 19 on Products.Description
```

#### Example passing model

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Happily adds an item with a null description:

```cs
ctx.Products.Add(new Product() { ProductId = 3});
ctx.SaveChanges(); //All good!
```

#### Analysis

Since you've named your context `testContext` in your example, perhaps what you're trying to do is perform unit/integration tests against SQLite in-memory, rather than your default production context.  Perhaps in your production context you *require* these columns to not be null (which is why the models are decorated so) - if that's the case, your **test models should be setup the same as production** - nulls should not be allowed in these columns.  Otherwise you're not testing the same thing, and the value of that test code is significantly reduced (bugs will sneak by that passed tests because values are null, but fail in production because of database constraints).

The same applies to dropping the `Foreign Keys` constraint - if, in production you expect foreign keys to be enforced and (for example) deletes to cascade, you should have the same behavior in your test setup.

#### Hacking the SQLite tables in memory

SQLite only supports a limited subset of [ALTER TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html), which excludes changing column definitions.  We can see how EF setup the table by trying the following:

```
var cmd = new SqliteCommand("SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE name='Products'", _connection);
Console.WriteLine(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

Which reports:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Products" (
    "ProductId" INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_Products" PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "Description" TEXT NOT NULL
)
```

To remove the constraint (not recommended) would require altering the table (not supported).  The only way around this is to follow [Making Other Kinds of Table Schema Changes](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html#making_other_kinds_of_table_schema_changes) which (overview) involves creating a second temporary table (without the constraint), copying the data, deleting the existing table, renaming the temporary table to the original name.  (For each model you're working with).  If you did this right after `ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();` you could just `DROP` the current tables and `CREATE` them without any `NOT NULL` constraints you wish to ignore (no need to copy data since none is loaded yet).  EF *depends* on the database to enforce the constraint, so you can now have a `[Required]` property on a model, that can be null because SQLite allows it - *this is a hack and not recommended*.

Answer (score 0):

First.. try calling Update() before SaveChanges()

To get to the heart of it just do the standard developer steps and debug it.  Wrap that call in a try catch and trace the issue from the the stack.  In the catch block log out to a file and look the resulting auto-rollback log

Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.Message + (ex.InnerException?.Message?.Replace("\r\n", " :: "))

You'll see something like this:
One or more errors occurred. constraint failed :: NOT NULL constraint failed: Product.ProductId

From there you can trace back the root cause and code for it.